# The conditions $a^2b^2=b^2a^2$ and $a^3b^3=b^3a^3$ make the group $G$ abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group. Assume that $a^2b^2=b^2a^2$ and $a^3b^3=b^3a^3$ for all $a, b \in G$. Prove that the group $G$ is abelian.

Also please tell me whether there is any standard approach in proving commutativity of groups like this problem.

Comment: Can you share your thoughts on the problem, and explain what you've tried and what's giving you difficulty?

Comment: The standard approach is to prove that ab = ba, using whatever are given.

Answer (score 10):

Let $M \subset G$ be the subgroup generated by all *squares* and let $N \subset G$ be the subgroup generated by all *cubes*. These subgroups are clearly *abelian normal* subgroups. Since 2 and 3 are coprime $G = MN$ (use Bézout's Theorem!) and $M \cap N$ is contained in the center $Z(G)$ of $G$. 
To prove that $G$ is abelian it suffices to show that $M$ and $N$ commute, that is $[M,N]=1$. Note that $[M,N] \subseteq (M \cap N)$. Let $x \in M$ and $y \in N$.
Then $[x, y] = x^{−1}y^{−1}xy \in M \cap N$. Hence $[x, y] = z$ with $z \in Z(G)$. Hence $y^{−1}xy = zx$, whence $y^{−1}x^3y=z^3x^3$. Since $x^3 \in N$ it commutes with $y$, so $z^3=1$. Similarly $z^2=1$. Since $2$ and $3$ are relatively prime, we conclude $z=1$.

Comment: Why is $M\cap N$ contained in $Z(G)$ ?

Comment: Take $g \in G$, then $g=mn$, with $m \in M$ and $n \in N$. If $x \in M \cap N$, then $xg=(xm)n=(mx)n$ because $M$ is abelian and $x \in M$. And $(mx)n=m(xn)=m(nx)$, because $N$ is abelian and $x \in N$. Hence $xg=m(nx)=(mn)x=gx$ and so $x \in Z(G)$.

Comment: Right. So your argument works in any case when $a^p$ commutes with $b^p$ and $a^q$ commutes with $b^q$ for any coprime pair of integers $(p,q)$, not just $(p,q)=(2,3)$.

Comment: @Ewan that is correct, it works for any pair of non-zero coprime integers!